# Three questions about table manipulation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

1. how to highlight the row when mouse is on,then de-highlight when mouse is out
2. how to update a specified row with new values?
3. how to get number of rows in table?

**EDIT**:
the one with best answer for q2 will be marked as answer for this post:)

Comment: I am not sure about the second question. 'How to update the specified row with new values'? Where are the values stored and what would be the structure of the values? Will it be some plain values or some HTML content? Do you need to update each cell or the entire row at once?

Comment: The values are all text values,provided by a form filled by user.I need to update the entire row at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Along with this CSS:

```
#mytable tr.active td {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

#### Two:

You said update a "row" but all you can really update is cells, unless you want to create whole new cells.

```
$(cell).html('Contents');
```

Or:

```
var $cell = $('<td>').html('Contents');
$(row).html($cell);
```

Or if a table row has 3 cells, to update the first one:

```
$(row).find('td').eq(0).html('Contents');
```

#### Three:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').length;
```

Comment: When you use $(row).html('Contents');
,will the listeners still work?I mean will the hover function be overwritten by this?

Comment: How to most efficiently update 6 cells?$(row).find('td').eq(0).html('Contents');
 will make it very very long.

Comment: It's not a big deal if you're just updating one row. You can cache the row cells by doing something like: var $cells = $(row).find('td'); and then $cells.eq(0).html('..'); and $cells.eq(1).html('...');

Comment: You can write a quick plugin to "compact" it if you really want.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

```
$("#table1 tr").hover(
   function()
   {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
   },
   function()
   {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
   }
```

For the third question:

```
var count = $("table1 tr").length
```

Comment: How does hover decide which function for mouseover and which for mouseout?

Comment: First one is hover second one is out. hover is not simply a wrapper for mouseover and mouseout, it takes care of a lot of problems that can be caused by children elements of the element you are hovering.

Comment: Right,and now let's focus on the second question:)

Comment: I am not sure about the second question. 'How to update the specified row with new values'? Where are the values stored and what would be the structure of the values? Will it be some plain values or some HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

**1**. http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover

I believe you can use this or .hover.

```
$('tr').mouseover(function() {

    $(this).addClass('over');

}).mouseout(function() {

    $(this).removeClass('over');

});
```

And add a over class in your CSS.

**2**. You don't update a row, you update the table cells inside the row.

```
$('tr:first td:first').text( 'something' )
```

**3**.

```
alert( $('table tr').length ); // count all descendant table rows
```

Comment: For 2,if there are 6 columns,how to update them most efficiently?

Comment: Unless you are noticing significant slowness and can provide said demo, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I don't mean it'll be slower,but looks very un-compact

Comment: your comment code in the other answer seems compact. un-compact usually means multiple lines of dom scripting, I say it's good enough as is.

Comment: Multiple lines of similar script,feels very un-compact.